# Joomla not showing SEF url for hidden menu items

Tags: joomla, url-rewriting, joomla-module

In my joomla project, there are some hidden pages ( means there is no menu direct to that page ). Some pages are redirecting to this page.

I am using this code to reach this page

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->redirect('index.php?option=com_package&view=testpage');
```

Working perfectly.

I enabled SEF URL, URL suffix, URL rewriting for the application. But these pages ( which doesn't have a proper menu ) not showing the SEF URL. But those pages which have the menu item to that page showing the SEF url.

So I added a hidden menu and added these all pages in that menu. But its not showing SEF URL.

Any idea for enable SEF URL to those pages ?

Please help
Thanks in advance

My Router.php looks like

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;


function GadminBuildRoute(&$query)
{
    $segments = array();

    if (isset($query['task'])) {
        $segments[] = implode('/',explode('.',$query['task']));
        unset($query['task']);
    }
    if (isset($query['id'])) {
        $segments[] = $query['id'];
        unset($query['id']);
    }

    return $segments;
}

/**
 * @param   array   A named array
 * @param   array
 *
 * Formats:
 *
 * index.php?/gadmin/task/id/Itemid
 *
 * index.php?/gadmin/id/Itemid
 */
function GadminParseRoute($segments)
{
    $vars = array();

    // view is always the first element of the array
    $count = count($segments);

    if ($count)
    {
        $count--;
        $segment = array_pop($segments) ;
        if (is_numeric($segment)) {
            $vars['id'] = $segment;
        }
        else{
            $count--;
            $vars['task'] = array_pop($segments) . '.' . $segment;
        }
    }

    if ($count)
    {   
        $vars['task'] = implode('.',$segments);
    }
    return $vars;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The hidden menu needs to be a menu module published (not suspended) with no position/a non-existing position; this way Joomla will consider it; also the menu items must be enabled.

Also the view has to be set with a default.xml in the view/tmpl folder with the same params as you want.

If this is still not working possibly there could be errors in the router.php

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply .. I have tried the first two metnods.. But thats not working .. I updated my question with my router.php can you please check ?

Comment: your router is not taking the view into consideration, but that's usually handled by the Joomla part (i.e. you have a menu that's pointing to the url). But even if it weren't, you would still get it working with an added &view=viewname at the end of the SEF url.  So I can't really help, try putting the menu item in a public menu, clean the cache and see if it helps...

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the URL through the router.
Try...

```
 $app->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_package&view=testpage'));
```